# Opening large file and turning it into hex results in OutOfMemory Exception VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exception, hex

I'm trying to make a program in vb.net and what it does is that when you open a file it turns the file opened into hexadecimal code, but the problem is that if I open a file that is large, It usually results in a OutOfMemory Exception.

I've tried some things but nothing worked.

```
        ToolStripLabel1.Text = "Status: Loading"
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Dim infoReader As IO.FileInfo
        infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        If Math.Truncate(infoReader.Length / 1024 / 1024) > 15 Then
            Dim x As MsgBoxResult
            x = MsgBox("Opening files bigger than 15MB can cause the program to be unresponsive for long periods of time, crash or throw a OutOfMemory exception, depending on the size of the file." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Are you sure you want to continue loading this file?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Warning - HEX EDITOR")
            If x = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    RichTextBox1.AppendText(String.Join(" ", File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))) 'This is where the exception would happen.
                ToolStripLabel1.Text = "Status: Idle"
            End If
        Else
            RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))
            ToolStripLabel1.Text = "Status: Idle"
        End If
    End If
    RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text
    NumericUpDown3.Maximum = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    NumericUpDown2.Maximum = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    NumericUpDown3.Value = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Label4.Text = "File Opened: " & OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading all the bytes in memory and then trying to execute an enourmous join of small 2 characters strings, you could load blocks of file data, convert a single block to hex and adding that conversion to the RichTextBox. All in an async/await fashion

```
Async Sub FillWithHex(rtb As RichTextBox, name As String)

    ' Arbitrary block size. Experiment with different sizes to
    ' see the difference in loading times vs smooth scrolling in richtextbox        
    Dim buff(1000000) As Byte

    Using fs = New FileStream(name, FileMode.Open)
        Using br = New BinaryReader(fs)
            While True
                Dim text = String.Empty
                buff = br.ReadBytes(1000000)
                Await Task.Run(Sub() text = String.Join(" ", buff.
                                Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))).
                                ConfigureAwait(True)
                rtb.AppendText(text)
                If buff.Length < 1000000 Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And call it from your code with

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
    FillWithHex(RichTextBox1, OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about doing that but I didn't know how to do it without crashing it or making errors.

Comment: I've got a problem, I can't save, Invaild Cast Exception                              If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
                Dim b As Byte() = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" "c).Select(Function(n) Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(n, 16)))
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, b, False)
            End If

Comment: What has this new problem in common with your original question? Please post a new question.